# Lightswitch: parameter with string and integer searching properties (is it possible?)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Just a quick question within the HTML Client side of Visual Studio 2013 Lightswitch, is it possible to set a parameter field based from a query to allow both sting and interger values to be searched...

an example would be StaffID(int) and StaffName(string)...

cheers guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - just add a .ToString() when you present on your int to the search query argument if Javascript isn't doing the conversion implicitly.

e.g.

```
searchString = intField.ToString() + ((intField==null)?" ";"") 
                  + strField.ToString() + ((strField==null)?" ";"")
                  + datefield.ToString()
```

Add this into the Executing event of the button that submits the search.  Make sure you use the "Contains" operator if you're going to try a concatenated search string like the one I've built here.