# Lightswitch 2013 - using a parameter to search for a string or int at the same time?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I am using the HTML Client and have currently got code that reloads the results based on user input, however i have been unable to work out how to use a query parameter to search for say an order number (3000) or a customers name...

is this possible?

thanks for any help/advice

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660497/lightswitch-parameter-with-string-and-integer-searching-properties-is-it-possi) - very similar scenario. :)


  [1]:

Comment: your experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution for the Details Picker window in the HTML Client.

1. Add Details picker for referenced table
2. Use the add data item and
       select the table that you are using as the details picker
3. set the filter to be in the pattern (WHERE --- ColumnName1 ---
   contains ---
       ColumnName1) etc